# Отсортировать List с LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

Мне нужно отсортировать в мою переменную StudentsWitHighestDebts типа var(List) из students только те объекты которые имеют значение в  s.ZachetDidNotPass максимум или (максимум -1) во всем List students

```
var StudentsWitHighestDebts = students
        .Where(s => s.ZachetDidNotPass.(some condition))
        .OrderBy(s => s.Name)
        .ToList();
```

Допустим у меня есть `List students` с объектами у которых значение `ZachetDidNotPass` равное 0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7 мне нужно занести в `StudentsWitHighestDebts` только тех, у кого эти значения максимальны или максимальны -1. Т.е тех, у кого 7 и 6

Помогите пожалуйста.Сам с помощью MSDN не смог разобраться...
Можно ли решить так:

```
foreach (var n in students)
{
    if (n.ZachetDidNotPass > maxZachDidNotPass)
    {
        maxZachDidNotPass = n.ZachetDidNotPass;
    }
    if (n.ExamDidNotPass > maxExamDidNotPass)
    {
        maxExamDidNotPass = n.ExamDidNotPass;
    }
}
var StudentsWitHighestDebts = students
        .Where(s => s.ZachetDidNotPass == maxZachDidNotPass
                    || s.ZachetDidNotPass == maxZachDidNotPass - 1
                       && s.ExamDidNotPass == maxExamDidNotPass
                    || s.ExamDidNotPass == maxExamDidNotPass-1)
        .OrderBy(s => s.Name)
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arr = new[] {0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7};
var res = from item in arr
          let max = arr.Max()
          where item == max || item == max - 1
          select item;
```

Ваши значения, думаю, подставить несложно

Comment: Но если же у меня динамичный список и там могут быть как 1 2 3, так и 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8, то мне нужно сначала через foreach найти max из списка, а потом уже делать выборку с помощью where. Так ведь?

Comment: вы этот код запустить пробовали? В нем все уже есть

Comment: просто немного не понял его, но попробовал сделать свой, посмотрите пожалуйста - в вопросе

Comment: @Sergey_Yysmaa ну вы подставьте свой код в приведенный, разве сложно?

Comment: Вроде бы все хорошо работает :). Спасибо!